# How to integrate maven 2 in an existing netbeans project?

Tags: netbeans, maven

How to integrate maven 2 in an existing netbeans project ?

I dont want to do it by *creating a new maven web app project and moving my files manually to
 the new project*(as I have versions of this project in my subversion repositories which I wont be able to link if I create new project), rather I need to integrate that in my already existing netbeans project. How do I go about it ? Would creating a pom.xml work ?

---

Maven 2 already installed on my machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about creating a new Maven Web Project and moving the `pom.xml` back to your existing Web Project? I mean:

1. Backup your projects
2. Create a new project with name `MavenWebTest`
3. Close your original project
4. Move the `pom.xml` from the `MavenWebTest` project to your original project's folder
5. Modify the `pom.xml`'s project specific settings (e.g. project name, dependencies)
6. Delete the `build.xml` and the whole `nbproject` folder
7. Move and rename the `web` folder to `src/main/webapp` (`webapp` is the new name) (use `svn mv` if you use Subversion)
8. Move `src/java` to `src/main/java` (`svn mv` here too)
9. Open you project again in Netbeans. It should be a Maven project now.
10. Delete the unnecessary `MavenWebTest` project

Anyway, creating an empty `pom.xml` also should work. You have to list your dependencies in the `pom.xml` and you have to set the project's name. Maybe other fine tunings also required to get the same result as Netbeans create without Maven. If you create the `pom.xml` with Netbeans (the MavenWebTest above) I suppose that most of Netbeans specific stuff already will be there.

If you are new to Maven I suggest you to check the free pdf/html books on [Sonatype's website](http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books).

Comment: Thanks palacsint! I am able to get started with Maven(in a new project) but I *dont want to* move to a new project since i wont be able to keep track with my old versions stored in subversion repositories under the name of this project

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The new project just temporarily required. Its `pom.xml` is important, it's useful to see how Netbeans generate `pom.xml` for its projects. I hope it's more clear now. Let me know if not.

Comment: @palacsint Once you have copied pom.xml, do you just run usual "build" or "run" buttons? Should Netbeans know it has to read pom.xml, what about classic configuration with "libraries" tabs ?

Comment: @HernánEche: Good question. I've updated the answer. Build and run should work. (I tested build only.) Unfortunately you have to add the dependencies to your POM by hand. Feel free to ask if something is not working or isn't clear.