# How to remove subversion repository for a specified project from netbeans?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I imported a project into subversion from netbeans now I simply want to undo that action and want the file stored in repository for that specified project *alone* be removed. How do I have to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete all `.svn` folders inside your project. Eclipse has a Team / Disconnect function for this. Maybe Netbeans also support it. If not, you can do it by hand or with a simple shell script.
2. With a repository browser delete the project's folder from SVN. I don't know that Netbeans supports it or not. If not, you can use the command line svn client (`svn delete <url>`) or [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot palacsint. Since you also answered my recent question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548008/how-to-integrate-maven-2-in-an-existing-netbeans-project , could you clarify if  I can anyhow merge my new maven project in subversion with the old project so that I can keep track of my older versions in subversion repositories in the new project

Answer (score 1):

Under TEAM menu. Choose DISCONNECT option to disconnect code from SVN